# Why won't my function extract json file and output it as an array on php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, extract

**Hi guys, I am struggling to return this json file as an array of individual list such as all countries "name", "iso_code" or "border". I can make it return the whole array from each country like;**

*0:
**geometry:** {type: "MultiPolygon", coordinates: Array(3)}
**properties:** {name: "Bahamas", iso_a2: "BS", iso_a3: "BHS", iso_n3: "044"}
type: "Feature"
[[Prototype]]: Object*

*1:
**geometry:** {type: "MultiPolygon", coordinates: Array(30)}
**properties:** {name: "Canada", iso_a2: "CA", iso_a3: "CAN", iso_n3: "124"}*

**but my aim is to just get individual ones like;**

*name: [ Bahamas, Canada, Denmark.... ]* **and** *iso_a3: [ BHS, CAN.... ]*

**I have tried many different ways of using *for* and *foreach* loops but all seems to return just one object like this;**

***name:** "Vanuatu"*

**Please can you help me**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true); 

// Read JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('countryBorders.geo.json');

//Decode JSON
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

//Print data

$countryBorders = $json_data["features"];   
$output["countryBorders"] = $countryBorders; // <-- returns the whole array 

$name = $countryBorders;    

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {     // <-- trying to return individual array 
    $output["name"] = $name[$i]["properties"]["name"];
}

// print_r($json_data);

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: If you need an array of stuff, then you need to *append to an array*: `$arr[] = $value`.

Comment: ok your answer was closer at first but now I've got the precise answer $justName[] = $name[$i]["properties"]["name"]; and then $output["name"] = $justName;